# Parsing redundant MySQL result into structured array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, parsing, join

my MySQL query output is

**dbcol_a | dbcol_b**
dataA1 | dataB1
dataA1 | dataB2
dataA2 | dataB3
dataA2 | dataB4
dataA2 | dataB5

I wanna parse into struturized array like this:

**arcol_a | arcol_b**
dataA1 | dataB1
----------| dataB2
dataA2 | dataB3
----------| dataB4
----------| dataB5

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$desired_array = array();
foreach ($query_output as $value)
{
  $desired_array[$value['arcol_a']][] = $value['arcol_b'];
}
```

This way you add each value in the second column to an array with an index of the first column.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make an hashtable called
   `arcol_a_array`.
2. Loop through your
   data.  For each row, check and see
   if the current `arcol_a` value is a key in
   the `arcol_a_array` array.  If not,
   add it.  The value of this key should be an array with one element - the value of the current row's `arcol_b`
3. If the `arcol_a` value existed in the `arcol_a_array` hashtable, modify the array to add the new value from `arcol_b`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   if(isset($arr[$row['arcol_a']])) {
    $arr[$row['arcol_a']][] = $row['arcol_b'];
  } else {
    $arr[$row['arcol_a']] = array($row['arcol_b']);
  }
}
```